# Restructuring Vectors in R

Tags: r, vector

if i have a file containing say (age,weight,city,town,height) is there a way to restructure the file so that all the numeric data eithier comes first or second such as (age,weight,height,city,town) in a simple way.  I want to know this because i have numeric and non numeric data about 10 columns long andhave to normalize using min/max only the numeric fields and it would be faster if they were all in one half of my dataset so i can just use a loop.  Sorry i'm new to R and i'm using it in mac os if thats important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing a sample data.frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(age=runif(10), weight=runif(10), city="New York", town="any", height=runif(10))
```

That's how you can order the columns:

```
dat.ordered <- dat[,order(sapply(dat,is.numeric), decreasing=T)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why bother reordering the columns, when you can simply loop over them and scale the numeric ones as needed?

```
dat <- data.frame(x1 = runif(10),
                  x2 = letters[1:10],
                  x3 = rnorm(10),
                  x4 = LETTERS[1:10])

data.frame(lapply(dat,function(x){if (is.numeric(x)) scale(x) else x}))
```

An equivalent, although somewhat bizarre looking, solution using some handy **plyr** functions:

```
require(plyr)
colwise(function(x){if (is.numeric(x)) scale(x) else x})(dat)
```

the versions `numcolwise` and `catcolwise` may also be of some interest (although they return only the columns they act on).